# Can you apply 3d box shadow effects (lifted corners) on top and bottom of div?

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

I am trying to create a lifted corner, 3d box effect on the bottom and top of a div.  I am able to create the desired effect on bottom of the div, but cannot figure out how to mimic the effect on the top.  Does anyone know how to achieve this on both the bottom and top of a div?

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rnejan81/

```
body {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}
.box h3{
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    top:80px;
}
.box {
    width:70%;
    height:200px;
    background:#FFF;
    margin:40px auto;
}
.effect2
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect2:before, .effect2:after
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.effect2:after
{
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}

<div class="box effect2 effect3">
    <h3>Effect 2</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: The effect in your code above uses all available pseudo elements (see: https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/). This means there are none left to repeat this effect on the top of the element. To do this on both the top and bottom you will need to change the code substantially. I believe it’s possible without images (or extra html) but don’t currently have time to say for sure and give you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrapped your box with another div and got the desired output

**EDIT:** Demo had some alignment issue before, thanks for @zaqx for pointing out that. this is the updated fiddle.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jinukurian7/nx4edx5a/8/)

```css
body {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}
.box h3{
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    top:80px;
}
.box {
    width:70%;
    height:200px;
    background:#FFF;
    margin:40px auto;
}

/*==================================================
 * Effect 2
 * ===============================================*/
.effect2
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect2:before, .effect2:after
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.effect2:after
{
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}

.effect-wrapper {
  position: relative;   
}
 .effect-wrapper:before, .effect-wrapper:after {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 16%;
    width: 52%;
    top: 8%;
    height: 5px;
    max-width: 300px;
    background: #777;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
    transform: rotate(183deg);
}

.effect-wrapper:after {
    transform: rotate(177deg);
    right: 16%;
    left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="effect-wrapper">
    <div class="box effect2 effect3">
        <h3>Effect 2</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is broken at small and large screen sizes. Really you have to be at the exact right width for it to look even slightly passsable.

Comment: @Zaqx : Thanks for pointing the mistake. I have updated the fiddle. cheers

Comment: Excellent CSS option.  With some minor adjustments to the "effect-wrapper" values, I was able to achieve a virtual copy of the 3D lift effect along the top.  Responsive to boot (I placed the "effect-wrapper" div inside the "box" div, which helped with the responsiveness for my need).  Thank you!

Comment: @Glorfindel I've added a snippet in the answer.